# Sequelize store object belongsTo with parent object which is not create

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

I wonder me how to correctly store object which have belongsTo relationship and foreign key column which is not null.

Example :

how i declare associations in index.js

```
User.hasMany(Product)

Product.BelongsTo(User)
```

Considered that in Product table we have a foreign key column NOT NULL references id in User Table.

According to sequelize documentation ([here](https://github.com/eddieajau/sequelize/blob/08e9df7295539cbf375fd30292d5e2c95e32d752/docs/docs/associations.md#creating-with-associations)),

I can write this :

```
    Product.create({
        title: 'Chair',
        User: {
        first_name: 'Mick',
        last_name: 'Broadstone'
       }
    }, {include: [ User ]});
```

but I always have this error :

[error: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint]

If I check SQL log, I notice that Sequelize is trying to insert Product before User with NULL into user_id column.

My questions are :

1/ foreign key column MUST be nullable with sequelize ?

2 this code insert User before and then Product with the needed relationship, doesn't it?

3/ Am I doing something wrong, as well ?

Comment: Can you post your model definitions?  In the example in the docs, the query will try to use the column `Product.UserId` as the foreign key.  You might be defining an extra column that you don't need if you're ok with sequelize creating the foreign key column.  Or you haven't properly defined your custom foreign key association.

Comment: Of course, that why I put option "underscored: true" to override camel Case and also use snake case. 
According to the error occured, my definition is correct because Sequelize found my column user_id into database. 
But into my INSERT request, it doesn't add User id but NULL

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's something else.  Could you still post your model definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it didn't work.

Just to explain, my code will create User instance and Product Instance,
But there's a known bug by sequelize team about validation of non null foreign key constraints.

To solve it two ways :

- put a dummy value
- make an other implementation like create parent instance then use create

I think this bug will be solve in future version of sequelize